# Chrome Restore Last Session

Tags: google-chrome, restore

I had an error, and after reopening Chrome, I couldn't get last tabs.

Using Control Shift T restored some windows, I saved them in bookmarks, just in case that is all I can restore.

Now I copied 3 files from Chrome Default Session folder into a separate folder for backup:

- Tabs_13337009203499971 - 3.02 MB size
- Session_13337010622180711 - 693 KB size
- Session_13337009343590954 - 1.15 MB size

Now If I close Chrome from task manager, copy these three files back again into Sessions default folder of Chrome , open again Chrome, press "restore" button, only a window of about 10 tabs opens.

How can I restore all tabs, as apparently possible by the size of Tabs and Session files?